# Interfaces providing default Interface Implementation

Tags: c#

If I have:

```
public interface IValueStorage : IComparable<IValueStorage>
{
    public int compareObject {get;}
    public int CompareTo(IValueStorage other)
    {
        return compareObject.CompareTo(other.compareObject);
    }
}
```

Why do I need to redefine the interface implementation of `IComparable` on any classes that implement this interface? Can I declare each member use the base implementation?

I would ordinarily just change this interface to an abstract class, but on this occasion, the implementers of this interface are all (and should remain) structs.

Comment: That interface doesn’t really make sense. IComparable is for values, not services

Comment: Apologies, I just made up this example as I didn't wish to share the whole interface.

Comment: So if you had a collection of services that had a `LastRun` property, you wouldn't potentially want to compare them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IService.CompareTo` does not override `IComparable<IService>.CompareTo`; it creates a new method that your structs must implement. In order to have an interface method override another interface's method, [you must use the explicit interface implementation syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#explicit-implementation-in-interfaces):

```
public interface IService : IComparable<IService>
{
    public int compareObject { get; }
    int IComparable<IService>.CompareTo(IService other)
    {
        return compareObject.CompareTo(other.compareObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bang tidy Joe! This works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

What you *actually* do in your case, is declaring a *new* `CompareTo` method, which has nothing to do with the same-named method declared in `IComparable<T>`. In other words, the following code:

```
public interface IService : IComparable<IService>
{
    public int CompareTo(IService other)
    {
        …
    }
}
```

is *not* a default implementation of `int IComparable<IService>.CompareTo(IService)`, but a standalone declaration of a *new* `int CompareTo(IService)` method.

Hence in the class implementing `IService`, there will be *two* implementations of `CompareTo`, one for each interface `IService` and `IComparable<IService>`.

As Joe Sewell pointed out [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74028827/245183), you can use the explicit implementation syntax in the derived interface:

```
int IComparable<IService>.CompareTo(IService other)
{
    …
}
```

Comment: Its the explicit implementation syntax which I was looking for, and I've been struggling to find the google search terms to discover independently. Joe was just a bit faster, so he gets the answer credit, but you are welcome to an upvote!